# Errors adding a new column to a table in MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm new to MySQL and database in general, however I'm having some issue when I try to add a new column of integer inside my table. To add a new column I'm doing so:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    # host, user, password and database
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered = True)

# some stuff to get the variable domain

mycursor.execute('ALTER TABLE domainsMoreUsed ADD {} INTEGER(10)'.format(domain)) # domain is a string
```

but i get this error:

```
raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You 
have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'in INTEGER(10)' at line 1
```

I get the same error above also trying:

```
mycursor.execute('ALTER TABLE domainsMoreUsed ADD %s INTEGER(10)' % domain)
```

Instead when I use:

```
mycursor.execute('ALTER TABLE domainsMoreUsed ADD %s INTEGER(10)', (domain))
```

i get:

```
raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

I read some post of other users about the same error, but I couldn't find what I need. I'm pretty sure about the SQL syntax being correct.
I'm using MySQL 8.0 with Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the string `domain` set to? The error message *`syntax to use near 'in INTEGER(10)' at line 1`*, implies "in", which is a reserved word. If you want to use that for a table or column name, you need to add backticks: " ` " (left of '1' on the top row of your keyboard) around them.

Change your queries like this:

```py
mycursor.execute('ALTER TABLE domainsMoreUsed ADD `{}` INTEGER(10)'.format(domain))

mycursor.execute('ALTER TABLE domainsMoreUsed ADD `%s` INTEGER(10)', (domain))
```

Comment: ok you solved my probem, thank you. I was having some trouble because I use a keyboard with QWERTY italian version and this symbol isn't present.

Comment: Welcome! Also, you should put backticks around any column or table name if it takes user-defined names, or if you need to use a reserved word as a name. In general, it's safer to always put names in backticks. See [this Q&A for more details](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/benefits-of-using-backtick-in-mysql-queries/23130).